# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 15, 3367

Tags: r

When I try to run `PanelMatch` in this setting, this error appear:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 15, 3367
```

What is wrong?

```
Yearby<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\usare R.csv",header = TRUE)
Yearby$EBITDA.MARGIN<- as.numeric(Yearby$EBITDA.MARGIN)
Yearby$Leverage<-as.numeric(Yearby$Leverage)
Yearby$ROA<-as.numeric(Yearby$ROA)
Yearby$Sales.Growth<-as.numeric(Yearby$ROA)
Yearby$Book.to.market<-as.numeric(Yearby$Book.to.market)
Yearby$Ln.of.Mv<-as.numeric(Yearby$Ln.of.Mv)
Yearby$Capex.to.sales<-as.numeric(Yearby$Capex.to.sales)
Yearby$Nwc.to.sales<-as.numeric(Yearby$Nwc.to.sales)
Yearby[is.na(Yearby)]<-0
PsweightROA5<-  PanelMatch(lag = 1, time.id = "Year", unit.id = "ï..Company.code",
                           treatment = "Targeted", refinement.method = "ps.weight",
                           data = Yearby, match.missing = TRUE, 
                           covs.formula = ~ Yearby$ROA,
                           size.match = 5 , qoi = "att" , outcome.var = "ROA",exact.match.variables=list("Industrial", "NR","Tmt","Consumer"),
                           lead = -1:2, forbid.treatment.reversal = FALSE, 
                           use.diagonal.variance.matrix = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you provide a small set of your data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes,  thank you for your interest!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x644a9lvgxpt7rl/set.csv?dl=0